# How do I split the date and time into two elements?

Tags: javascript, html, date

I've made an object that displays the date and time live.

I would like to know how I can separate the time part from the date so I can have it in its own HTML element so I can apply different styling to it?

I'm not that advanced with JavaScript, and I find working with the date object very complicated.

**LiveDateTime.js**

```
'use strict';

function LiveDateTime(dateEl, options) {
    this.dateEl = dateEl;
    this.options = options;

    this.timestamp;
    this.offset;

    this.start();
}

LiveDateTime.prototype = {
    start: function () {
        var now = !this.timestamp ? new Date() : new Date(this.timestamp),
            self = this;

        (function update() {
            self.dateEl.innerHTML = now.toLocaleString(self.options.locale, self.options);

            now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1);

            self.timeoutId = setTimeout(update, 1000);
        })();
    },

    stop: function () {
        clearTimeout(this.timeoutId);

        this.timeoutId = undefined;
    }
};
```

**Usage**

```
var liveDateTime = new LiveDateTime(document.getElementById('date'), {
    locale: 'FR',
    weekday: 'long',
    day: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: '2-digit'
});

//output example: vendredi 13 mars 2015 23:14:12
```

**HTML**

```
<span id="date"></span> - <span id="time"></span>
```

Comment: Check into [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/). It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Date objects are pretty simple. They have a [*time value*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) that is milliseconds since an epoch and an offset that is from system settings. It also has a bunch of handy methods to do stuff, but it doesn't do formatting of values very well. That's the bit where you might need a bit of help but there are methods to write times and dates (per QuentinUK's answer) or you can format them yourself using methods like *getHours*, *getMinutes*, *getFullYear*, *getMonth*, etc.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `date.toLocaleDateString()` for the date part, and `date.toLocaleTimeString()` for the time part.

Comment: The problem with the *toLocale* methods is that you never know what you're going to get from host to host. Safari & OmniWeb: *14 March 2015*, Firefox: *14/3/2015*, Chrome: *3/14/2015*, IE: *Saturday, March 14, 2015*.

Comment: If you want that you'd have to make your own version of toLocale. Not easy if you want days and months in words.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, but I think that's only when you aren't giving it any formatting options.

Comment: @RobG, the formatting options are a recent addition, it's only just in IE (version 11) and not in Safari yet.

Comment: @KidDiamond—there are no formatting options in ECMA-262 ed 5 or the ed 6 draft, so it will be a very long time before browsers consistently provide them. As it stands, the result of *toLocaleString* is completely implementation dependent and different across browsers. Writing a function to produce a particular format date string is trivial.

Comment: @QuentinUK—there is [*ECMA-402*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/), which has been a standard since December 2012, but I don't see widespread adoption. The [*latest draft*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/lib/exe/fetch.php?id=globalization%3Aspecification_drafts&cache=cache&media=globalization:ecma-402-2-draft-rev10-2015-02-17.pdf) was last month.

Answer (score 9):

You can format your date using Date available methods:

```js
var now = new Date()
var date = now.toLocaleDateString();
var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(date + ' ' + time)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not that advanced with JavaScript, and I find working with the date object very complicated.

Working with date in JS could be indeed complicated and frustrating. But that could be a pleasure by using libraries such [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

**So as to get the date formatted as you need :**

```
moment().format('dddd Do MMMM YYYY'); // vendredi 13 mars 2015   (with FR locale)
                                      // Friday 13th March 2015  (with EN locale)
```

**And for getting the hour :**

```
moment().format('H:mm:ss'); // 23:36:15
```

These are just tiny examples of the possibilities of the library.

For other formatting patterns, refer to [this table of the documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's `split()` method

```
var date = liveDateTime.split(" ");
    var weekday = date[0];
    var day = date[1];
    var month = date[2];
    var year = date[3];
var time = date[4].split(":");
    var hour = time[0];
    var minute = time[1];
    var second = time[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var now = new Date()
var date = now.toLocaleDateString();
var time = now.toLocaleTimeString();
console.log(date + ' ' + time)
```