# Convert datetime to date and time format separately in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I have this html for my calendar

```
<!--Grid column-->
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="md-form mb-0">
    <input placeholder="Selected date" data-toggle="datepicker" type="text" id="myDate" name="myDate" class="form-control datepicker">
    <label for="myDate" id="dateLabel">Estimated Start Date</label>
</div>
</div>
 <!--Grid column-->
```

Currently I have this

`var est_start_date = $(this).attr('data-esd');`

and the value I place it to the textbox using this code

`$('#myDate').val(est_start_date);`

which contains value like this

[image]

As you can notice the data includes the time also

How can I format the datetime to something like this `MM/DD/YYYY`

[image]

Also separate the time to this format

[image]

Comment: have you looked at `moment` js library? https://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let date=new Date(document.querySelector('#myDate').value)

Date part ===> date.toLocaleDateString() .

Time part ====> date.toLocaleTimeString() for the time part.

from below answer:

[Split the date and time in two elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042911/split-the-date-and-time-in-two-elements)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the javascript date object to get the required format. Use this,

```js
function formatDate(date) {

const arr = [date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate(), date.getFullYear()]
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  var date = arr.join("/");
  return date + " " +strTime;

}

console.log(formatDate(new Date));
```

Comment: `date.getMonth is not a function`

Comment: First get value from datepicker in date format using `$('#datepicker').val()`, then pass this value to function `formatDate`. If you are calling `getMonth` on string it won't work it should be `javascript date object`

Comment: `let myDate = new Date(document.querySelector('#myDate').value)` and then call `formatDate(myDate)`

Comment: The problem is I'm getting the value of this data attribute `var est_start_date = $(this).attr('data-esd');` and put to the calendar but the `var est_start_date` contains the value something like this `2019-10-21 1:41:00` because this data attribute value is coming from datetime field on my db

Comment: @KingRG I have added a new answer, I hope it answers your question

Answer (score 1):

Use this to convert your date to required format,

```js
 function formatDate(date) {
  date = date.split(" ");
  let dateOne = date[0];
  let time = date[1];
  time = time.split(":");
  time.forEach((val,index)=>{
   if(val.length <2){
    val = "0" + val;
    time[index] = val;
   }
  })
  time = time.join(":");

  let str = `${dateOne}T${time}.000Z`;

  let offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()*60*1000;

  date = new Date( (new Date(`${dateOne}T${time}.000Z`)).getTime() + offset);

  const arr = [date.getMonth() + 1, date.getDate(), date.getFullYear()]
  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  var date = arr.join("/");
  return date + " " +strTime;
 } 

 let date = '2019-10-21 1:41:00';
 console.log(formatDate(date));
```